# H264 over RTP - Blurred Section of Video

Tags: h.264, rtp

I've got an packetizer which is taking NAL units from an H264 stream and sending them out over RTP using UDP.

Everything works, but the top ~15% of the resulting video when viewed in VLC or FFPlay is blurred (screenshot linked below).

The stream uses FU-A but this matches the spec in RFC6184.

If I save the nal units to a file before the packetization it plays perfectly without the blur.

I've spent quite a while trying to work out what's going wrong with it and have run out of ideas, so was hoping someone here might have some pointers to help me out?

Any help very much appreciated.

[Blur at top of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXtwt.png)

Comment: I think your packetizer is corrupting video data. RTP has fixed header size. So after packetization dump the packet from RTP header offset and compare it with your packetizer input. If they are different then you need to look into your packetizer code.